# How to get json encoding for a list sql database table names and data in them in php

Tags: php

How can I list names of tables in sql database and the table columns for the each table and then get a json encoding of the results in PHP?
Here is code to display tables:

```
$result = mysql_query("show tables"); // run the query and assign the result to $result
while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
// go through each row that was returned in $result
echo($table[0] . "<BR>");    // print the table that was returned on that row.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array/object and add the data to it. To get a json result just call `json_encode` on the array/object.

Here is what I would do:

```
// Create an object
$results = new stdClass();

// Get all tables
$result = mysql_query("show tables");

// Always check if the query returned anything to prevent possible errors
if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    // Loop through each table
    while($table = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        // Get the columns in the table
        $resultColumns = mysql_query("show columns from ".$table);

        if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
            // Columns found. Create a new property in the object and assign the columns to it
            $tableColumns = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultColumns);
            $results[$table] = $tableColumns;
        }
        else {
            // No columns found. Create a new property in the object and assign a blank array.
            $results[$table] = [];
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can return that data as a json with `json_encode($results)`.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

As a side note, I would look to use **mysqli**, not mysql (as it is now depreciated). The syntax for it is basically exactly the same, but you need to pass the connection variable as the first parameter in most cases. So it would be useful to use create a database/connection class and call to those methods, instead of calling `mysql` or `mysqli` functions directly. 
See here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp
And here (an example): https://www.johnmorrisonline.com/simple-php-class-prepared-statements-mysqli/

**Note:** This is pseudo code and not tested but should be okay. Let me know if you need any help with it.

Comment: $resultColums= mysqli_query($con,"show colums from".$table );  I get , Notice: Array to string conversion         and $results[$table]=[] ;   i get, Fatal error: Uncaught error. Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. Help me solve these

Comment: <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DBNAME");
$results = new stdClass();
$result = mysqli_query($con,"show tables");
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0) {
    while($table = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $resultColumns = mysqli_query($con,"show columns from ".$table);
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0) {
            $tableColumns = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultColumns);
            $results[$table] = $tableColumns;
        }
        else {$results[$table] = []}
    }
}
echo json_encode($results);
?>